# How to create website folder above root directory of admin in PHP

Tags: php, apache, ftp, webserver

I've tried to figure out the best way to create a website programmatically in PHP but I couldn't find any similar questions here or elsewhere.
The situation is this:
I have an `admin dashboard` and a `DB` connected to this `admin dashboard`. 
In this dashboard I create a website with all the necessary settings. Like list of foods and images and colors etc.
When I save a website in the dashboard I need to create a website folder above the root directory of the `admin panel` on my `web server`. 
So it creates all the files and folders which will be uploaded to that folder and be connected to the admin DB to get the data.
The thing is that I want to create dozens of websites with the same structure but with different data and colors etc., not as `subdomains` of the admin dashboard but as a `main domain`.
Of course the domains will be created manually in my c-panel. 
It's not about the coding but about the approach to this problem.
Would be happy about any suggestions.

Comment: If you are trying to do this through a web interface you simply won't be able to do it. By its very definition folders above the web root are not visible to the web server.

Comment: @Dave "can't" is not entirely accurate; "shouldn't" is certainly good advice. Depending on file permissions and other system configuration, this can certainly be done. If the user as which PHP is running has write access, it will work. It is probably not the best(or safest) solution, though.

Comment: How about most likely can't? If file permissions and other configurations allow it something is probably broken and the hosting is suspect. Under normal circumstances one should not be able to write things above the root (other than a temp directory).

Comment: @Dave That's fair. Certainly being able to alter the web server configuration would be a poor configuration. It is certainly not something that would be available or recommended under normal circumstances. I just wanted to point out that is is possible, regardless of whether or not it is reasonable or a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the websites are all sharing the same code base, but just have different data, I would consider not creating different folders at all. Store all of your data for each site in the database.

You can then create a single virtual host in Apache set as the default that will handle all requests that do not explicitly match another. Your PHP code can then look at the `Host` header to determine which site is being accessed, query the database to determine if it is valid and load the data, and then serve the appropriate content.

I would not advise dynamically altering system configuration with PHP. Though it could be done safely, this seems overly complex and prone to errors that could be significant security risks.

Obviously, there are many approaches to this and ultimately the correct one will depend on your use case and the customization and uniqueness of each site.

Comment: would this work also when users access the websites each with a different URL. For example if someone accesses with example1.com and another with example2.com?

Comment: Exactly. Apache will route any requests that do not explicitly match a virtual host by domain to the default one(for instance, `*:443`). The same code would be executed for any requested domain(`example1.com`, `example2.com`, etc.) and would programmatically determine the correct content. The only configuration per domain would be pointing the DNS to the correct IP.

Comment: Thanks and another problem would be if this would create any problems with payment gateways as in if there would be a security risk detected by for example PayPal and would block the payment?

Comment: Externally, nothing would know the difference(though you may deduce this behavior by noting that these domains route to the same IP). This piece would be no different than if you explicitly configured a virtual host for each domain. This is all internal to your servers, users or other services should not be able to tell the difference if this is implemented correctly. PayPal should not have any issue with it.